# priority_queue with custom comparator as a class method

Tags: c++, priority-queue

i have code like this

```
priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(&VD::CompareByDistance)> pqDistances(&VD::CompareByDistance);
```

where

```
class VD 
{
    ...
    bool CompareByDistance(int indexLeft, int indexRight) const;
};
```

But i get error

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

How can i pass class member as a compator, the thing is that i want comparator to access its instance fields. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, is this comparison function really non-const? That does not feel very idiomatic.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it is const, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool CompareByDistance(int indexLeft, int indexRight);
```

takes three arguments: The `this`-pointer and the both `int`s.

Besides this being the wrong number of arguments for the `priority_queue` template parameter: What instance of `VD` do you expect this non-static method to be called on?

A workaround for this would be "carrying" the instance with you like this:

```
VD v;
auto comp = [&](int i1, int i2) {return v.CompareByDistance(i1, i2);}
```

This `comp` object would now be a valid template argument for your queue. For example:

```
struct A{
    bool compare (int, int) const {return true;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto comp = [&](int i, int i2) {return a.compare(i, i2);};
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)> q (comp);
}
```

Comment: i have the same error. The lambda captures this, and it is a problem

Comment: @Yola Did you forget to pass the `comp` to the constructor of the queue? Works for me. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fed72acd2d03b6d7))

Comment: Is the 'this' pointer actually used in CompareByDistance though? Otherwise we could simply make it static

Comment: @KABoissonneault *" the thing is that i want comparator to access its instance fields."* So I guess that won't work.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Alright, missed that line.

Unrelated, but I don't recommend using generalized lambda capture.
The capture list should be [&v] or [&a] instead.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Depending on what he actually is doing here, he might even want to capture be copy. I'll just leave that to OP who (hopefully) knows his actual code and what it is doing.